# drupal 7 How can I allow my users to flag/ subscribe to taxonomy terms and nodes?

Tags: drupal-7, flags, drupal-taxonomy

We all know that the Flags module helps with flagging nodes.
But how can we flag taxonomy terms? So when new nodes use one of those taxonomy terms as a 'tag', everyone who has subscribed or flagged that term,can find out about it!

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomy terms are fieldable in Drupal 7, and according to [this post](http://drupal.org/node/1003342) in the issue queue for the [Flag Terms module](http://drupal.org/project/flag_terms) (Drupal 6 only), you can attach flags to taxonomy terms using said fields.